# BasicCompiler: wanted binaries which BC.exe or QB.exe (compiler) generates

Tags: dos

I was in charge of analyze and reverse engineering the old unknown EXE for past few month. The binary works on MS-DOS for NEC-PC98 (retro PC), old (20years more ago), nobody knows how it's made.

I done the job and knew the binary had been generated by unknown vendor's basic compiler. The binary has interesting technique; well-designed VM, partial relocated overlaying like a DLL, data-section-compression and self melting. It highly impressed me. So I'd like to know the compiler generates the binary.

For now I guess that the vendor may be Microsoft. I'd try to use QuickBasic's compiler (<del>BC.EXE</del>`QB.EXE`) and would generate small binary but unfortunately I'm not owner the old toolchain.

So I'd love to ask someone a favor, if you have any Microsoft's Basic Compiler then goto dig your garage and put an old binary generated by such a compiler on me. I'll see it and want to identify the compiler and vendor.

The binary has following characteristics:

- indicates magicWORD, 0x1e, on its exe header's reloc table offset address field
- start-up-code/address is in higher address (backward of exe)
- includes common libraries (such a libc) are relocatable on a single binary
- generates fully native code not an P-code. a `call` matches a (unknown) VM-OP-code
- Character code is ASCII/Shift-JIS big endian(cp932, multibyte code for Japanese)
- floating points IEEE754 not MS-FP
- rodata sections are easily compressed (optional?)

the EXE address map:

```
00000: MZ HEADER
00200: module1-header
00230: module1-code
00xxx: module1-data (compressed)
       : (repeats by module-N)
yyyyy: native libraries 
zzzzz: startup code
ZZZZZ: relocation table (for calling a library)
```

---

`BC.EXE`, Microsoft PDS, is one of interested products for me.
Please compile a simple code like this:

`X = 0.5 * 100.0
PRINT X
FOR I=0 TO 16 
    PRINT "Hello, World"
NEXT I`

and I would appreciate it if you send me an output executable.

Comment: Wasn't QuickBasic called `qb.exe`? I remember using both `bc.exe` (Borland C) and QB, without having to add paths. Also, QuickBasic was a product in itself – I've never seen referred to it as "Microsoft's Basic Compiler". OTOH: that [wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickBASIC) startup screen shot looks eerily familiar ...

Comment: The professional version of MS-DOS BASIC was called PDS (Professional Development System) and it's last version was 7.1  I still use it because I still have clients who run my DOS version of my accounting package.  It's compiler is BC.EXE.  What exactly are you looking for?  A sample program to decompile?